# How can I use NewRelic for my Meteor application?

Tags: meteor

I'm hosting my Meteor app on Heroku and would like to have more monitoring capabilities rather than `heroku logs --tail`. NewRelic could be a good option, though its node.js agent is still in beta. Does anybody tried to use it with Meteor app?

Comment: Did you have any success running NewRelic with Meteor.
I added a package, with new relic to my Meteor app, and when I push it to heroku, it logs an error: Unable to read configuration file /app/newrelic.js

On the NewRelic site it says the the newrelic.js has to be copied to the root. Ive copied it to the root of my app, but it still won't find it.
How did you managed this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Old answer available below.

### UPDATE FOR 2014:

*Meteor version as of time of writing: `0.9.4`. sweet. almost at 1.0!*

OK I decided to edit this as this still gets upvotes with it being very outdated now.

As of Meteor 0.7+ or around that (can't remember exactly), require-ing in Meteor has been long changed from `__meteor_bootstrap__.require` to `Npm.require`

`var require = Npm.require;
var newrelic = require('newrelic');`

This follows the **Npm in a smart package pattern**. [Read more about it here](http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/npm#NPM%20in%20a%20Smart%20Package)

Excerpt for the lazy (thanks, [Meteorpedia](http://www.meteorpedia.com)!):

> ### NPM in a Smart Package
>
> 1. In your `package.js`, add a clause like:
>
>    Npm.depends({
>         "walk": "2.2.1"
>      });
> 2. Use `Npm.require` instead of require, e.g.
>
>    var http = Npm.require('http');

But seriously, read the whole thing on meteorpedia. It's worth your time.

**Alternatively**, you can also use [arunoda](http://arunoda.me/)'s excellent NPM smart package. Check it out here! https://github.com/meteorhacks/npm

#### *Old answer*:

Taken from [this guide](https://coderwall.com/p/2fveyq), You should be able to install the newrelic agent like any other npm module. In your meteor project folder:

```
$ cd .meteor/local/build/server
$ npm install newrelic
```

Now, you can use it via `require`:

```
var require = __meteor_bootstrap__.require;
var newrelic = require('newrelic');
```

Then, configure your agent as specified here: https://github.com/newrelic/node-newrelic/#configuring-the-agent

if you need to use env vars specified in that guide, run the `meteor` command with the env vars set e.g.:

```
$ NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME=mynodeapp meteor
```

That should be it, but I haven't really used it extensively because I haven't found any reason yet to do so. Let us know what you get to!