# How to use Prerenderio with Meteor?

Tags: meteor, prerender

I would like to use prerenderio with Meteor instead of phantomjs on the server with modulus.

However given the examples they provide, I'm not sure how to integrate it. They only provide a node express middleware which doesn't translate 100%.

Comment: Try [this prerendering service](https://ostr.io/info/prerendering) made specially for Meteor.js

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For SEO purposes? I mean, what else could it be? ;)

Firstly, remove the spiderable package if you haven't already.

Second, drop this at your server-side code (for example `server/prerenderio.js`):

```
// Use Prerender with your token
var prerenderio = Npm.require('prerender-node').set('prerenderToken', 'YOUR_TOKEN'); 
// Feed it to middleware! (app.use)
WebApp.connectHandlers.use(prerenderio);
```

If you're wondering about Npm.require (or Meteor.require), See this answer (by me, sorry for shameless plug) for the gist: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16481897/951773

Source: I've used prerenderio successfully for a couple of our clients.

![Good luck!][1]

### EDIT:

Since there has been major differences now between express request and response objects to meteor's connect objects, it went to really complicated now. But this has been addressed now and hopefully the PR I put in works:

https://github.com/dfischer/meteor-prerenderio/issues/1

TL;DR Thanks to this question now we have a [prerender.io meteor module](https://github.com/dfischer/meteor-prerenderio).

Comment: I tried installing prerender-node with the meteorhacks npm lib and I get this error: https://gist.github.com/dfischer/ccaa63812c67cfb388c3 thoughts? Is it because I'm using meteorhacks npm lib?

Comment: Created a package here: https://github.com/dfischer/meteor-prerenderio still same error... TypeError: Object #<IncomingMessage> has no method 'get'

Comment: Weird, ok let me look into this when I finish current work. let's work on the package one when I get to it.

Comment: great - I can add you as a collaborator. What's your github username? Thank you :)

Comment: Oh wait, could you try something first.. can you try `rawConnectHandlers` instead of `connectHandlers` ?

Comment: same issue with rawConnectHandlers :(

Comment: I see a lot of developers has trouble integrating prerenderio to theirs webapps, that's we me moved to [prerendering.com](https://prerendering.com), highly recommended, it took less than 15 mins, thanks to atmosphere package.